# Proof verification - If $a|bc$ and $(a,b) = 1$, then $a|c$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

> if $a|bc$ and $gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $a|c$

We know that $b|bc$

also $a|bc$

and $(a,b)= 1 \rightarrow \big(ab=lcm(a,b\big)\big| bc$

so $a | c$.

Is this proof correct?

Edit: I think assuming $lcm(a,b)=ab$ is too much so here is another elementary proof:

$(a,b)=1\rightarrow \exists p,q \in Z \ni pa +qb = 1 \rightarrow pac + qbc = c $

now $a|ac$ and $a|bc$ so $a|c$

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: How do you prove that the lcm of $a$ and $b$ is $ab$?

Comment: @Lordsharktheunknown, I think he used $a\times b=gcd(a,b)\times lcm(a,b)$.

Comment: @Martund He/she didn't mention that, but is she or he had, I'd ask him/her how that was proved.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I think I know where you're getting at. I edited my post

Comment: Your new argument is very much a standard proof.

Comment: I worry about these proofs.  Assuming that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $lcm(a,b)=ab$ and that if $a|m$ and $b|m$ then $lcm(a,b)|m$ seem to me to not be any more fundamental then the result you are proving.  I'd worry about checking the proofs of *those* assumptions and verify you didn't use something equiv to what your are proving. (One should always be prepared to prove use statements anyway.)  Which is not to say your proof *isn't* valid.  It might very well be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof is correct, another one could be using bezout's identity. $$gcd(a,b)=1$$
$$\Longrightarrow \exists x,y\in \mathbb Z : ax+by=1$$
$$\Longrightarrow acx+bcy=c$$
LHS is divisible by $a$, so is RHS.